# how to implement push notification using GCM in android studio using php?

Tags: php, android, push-notification, server, google-cloud-messaging

I am trying to get notification in my app using GCM. i am using android studio tool and i tried lots of tutorials. most of them where done using eclips tool. 
finally, i tried this one,
       http://rmarcejaeger.com/2015/09/18/tutorial-how-to-implement-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-for-android-part-1-client-app/#comment-576070, 
    https://github.com/googlesamples/google-services/tree/master/android/gcm

and i finish android client part using above tutorial. But the problem is, i need to setup app server in php which connect my application through GCM. i have no idea to make it possible. i tried the follwing link,
      https://developers.google.com/cloud-messaging/server

but i couldn't get much more.So please anyone suggest me better solution.

Answer (score 3):

you need to understand below steps

[image]

for more details   [Android Push Notifications using Google Cloud Messaging (GCM), PHP and MySQL](http://www.androidhive.info/2012/10/android-push-notifications-using-google-cloud-messaging-gcm-php-and-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

First you need to create browser key from Console.

This is the code you need to add for Sending notification GOOGLE_API_KEY is the key you created from Console.

```html
<?php
 
class GCM {
 
    //put your code here
    // constructor
    function __construct() {
         
    }
 
    /**
     * Sending Push Notification
     */
    public function send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message) {
        // include config
        include_once './config.php';
 
        // Set POST variables
        $url = 'https://android.googleapis.com/gcm/send';
 
        $fields = array(
            'registration_ids' => $registatoin_ids,
            'data' => $message,
        );
 
        $headers = array(
            'Authorization: key=' . GOOGLE_API_KEY,
            'Content-Type: application/json'
        );
        // Open connection
        $ch = curl_init();
 
        // Set the url, number of POST vars, POST data
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
 
        // Disabling SSL Certificate support temporarly
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
 
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($fields));
 
        // Execute post
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        if ($result === FALSE) {
            die('Curl failed: ' . curl_error($ch));
        }
 
        // Close connection
        curl_close($ch);
        echo $result;
    }
 
}
 
?>
```

Now using this method of GCM class you can send notification to the device by calling its method.
pass  reg.id that is token id you got from Android device and message you want to pass.

```html
$gcm = new GCM();
$result = $gcm->send_notification($registatoin_ids, $message);
echo $result;
```